# adding only the last node in the linkedlist in java

Tags: java, linked-list, addition

Empty is a class that has getValue() as a method and this.k is a matrice which has Object[][] as type and every field of it could have tree type of objects: Empty, Neutral and Other.
I wanna insert in a linkedlist many matrices changing only a value

```
    public LinkedList<Object[][]> increment(int i,int j)
    {
    LinkedList<Object[][]> l=new LinkedList<>();
    Object[][] o;
    for(int a=1;a<10;a++)
    {
        o=this.k;
        ((Empty) o[i][j]).setValue(a);
        l.add(o);
    }
    for(Object[][] oo:l)
    {
        System.out.println(((Empty) oo[i][j]).getValue());
    }
    return l;
    }
```

output suppose to be like that:
`1`
`2`
`3`
`4`
`5`
`6`
`7`
`8`
`9`
but it prints only the last number like that:
`9`
`9`
`9`
`9`
`9`
`9`
`9`
`9`
`9`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, every element in the `LinkedList<Object[][]> l` referenced the same `this.k`, and it holds the value which you modified in the last. please new the object of `k` in each iteration.

Comment: Like this Object[][] o=k; ?

Comment: Show me the definition of `k`

Comment: private Object k[][];

Comment: `o = new Object[i+1][j+1]`

Comment: Brother thanks it does work when I did `o=new Object[i+1][j+1]; o[i][j]=new Empty(a);` instead of `o=this.k; ((Empty) o[i][j]).setValue(a);`

Comment: but I didn't get the values of `this.k` because I just wanted to change specific value  that have the parameters i and j